# Nullspace of matrix where elements equals zero.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to find the nullspce of this matrix. I have set the matrix equal to 0 and row reduced, but my problem now is that I dont know how to interpret that all x-values are equal to 0. I see that $x_1$ and $x_5$ are free variables, but how can this be used to find the nullspace and the basis of the matrix?

$$
rref
\left(
\begin{matrix}
0 & 0.7 & 0 & 0 & 0 &| 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0.5 & 0 & 0 &| 0 \\
0 & 0.3 & -1 & 0.65 & 0 &| 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0.5 & -1 & 0 &| 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0.35 & 0 &| 0 
\end{matrix}
\right)
=
\left(
\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 &| 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 &| 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &| 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &| 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &| 0 
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

Comment: It means that any vector of the form $(x_1, 0,0,0,x_5)$ for any $x_1, x_5$ will be killed by your matrix, and therefore is an element in the null set.

Comment: @Arthur Ok. So that means that the basis will be {{1,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,1}}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $x_1$ and $x_5$ are free variables so let them be given arbitrary values $r$ and $s$. On back substitution (or direct multiplication) we see that $x_2=x_3=x_4=0$. So the null space is $$\{(r,0,0,0,s):r,s\in\mathbb R\}.$$

Clearly this is spanned by the vectors $(1,0,0,0,0)$ and $(0,0,0,0,1)$ which constitute its basis.